# Scaling GGplot based on other dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph showing total sales per state. I have another date frame with population data among other measures per city that can be rolled up to state. Given that there is a large variance in the population per state, I wanted to scale the sales by the % of the states population relative to the  total population. - i.e. See if particular states actually buy more or not relative to their size. Any ideas where to start pls?

Very basic code I am using to start with.

```
State_Sales_Summary_Plot <- ggplot(
    data=Customers_DF_Clean, 
    aes(x=State.Code, y=Total.Spent)
  ) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Population Version of the code below:

```
Population_Per_State <- ggplot(
    data=SSC_IndexData_Education_and_Occupation_DF_Clean,
    aes(x=State.Name, y=Population)
  ) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: `join` your two datasets by a variable they have in common (`State.Code` or `State.Name` are obvious candidates).  Calculate sales per unit population.  Plot this derived variable.  Without access to your data it's difficult to be more precise.  Oh, and welcome to SO!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).